# Avoid Duplicates on Database- Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, duplicates

I am programming on vb.net and using ms-access and using ADODB recordset. I think it will be hard for me to explain, I hope you guys can understand my question.
I want to avoid duplicate Value in the database, and when is about to duplicate, it does not add anything. I have two datagradeview. One with all the Groups that I have in a table on access, lets call this gridAllGroup. Another datagradeview has only the Groups in a questionary, this one is called gridGroup. I have a button that it will pass the selected group from gridAllGroup to gridGroup.
Actually it is 3 grids.
First is the Questionary, then the selected questionary will populate the gridGroups with  groups that is from that questionary.

I tried to get the value from ID Questionary and ID Group, and then compare if already exists in the table..But I think it is wrong way I did.

This is the button that will pass the selected group

```
s = "Select * from rrQuestionaryGroup where ID_Questionary = " & Val(Trim(lblIDQuestionary.Text)) & " and ID_Group = " & Val(Trim(lblIDGroup.Text)) & ""

        retval = getRS(s, rs, False, serror)

        If retval Then
            MsgBox("Group already in this questionary")
        Else
            rs.AddNew()
            rs.Fields("ID_Questionary").Value = lblIDHoldQuestionary.Text
            rs.Fields("ID_Group").Value = lblIDHoldGroup.Text
            rs.Fields("Order").Value = lblIDHoldOrder.Text
            rs.Update()
            rs.Close()
        End If
```

```
Public Function getRS(ByVal sql As String, rs As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal RO As Boolean, ByRef sErro As String) As Boolean
        Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection

        On Error Resume Next
        Con.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users.mdb;Persist Security Info=true")
        Con.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient

        rs.Open(sql, Con, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Return True
        Else

            sErro = Err.Description
            Return False

        End If
        On Error GoTo 0


    End Function
```

I hope this is enough info to understand. Thanks in advance, any help I would be thankful.

Comment: You will need to post more of your code, in particular, the `getRS()` function.

Comment: @RobertBaron Okay....that one is just to connect

Comment: Why ADODB? ADO.net has been around for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetRS()` function returns `True` if it successfully opens a `Recordset`, but that does not tell us anything about whether the `Recordset` contains records are not. For that, you have to use the `RecordCount` property of the `Recordset`. Something like this.

```
If retval Then
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Group already in this questionary")
    Else
        rs.AddNew()
        rs.Fields("ID_Questionary").Value = lblIDHoldQuestionary.Text
        rs.Fields("ID_Group").Value = lblIDHoldGroup.Text
        rs.Fields("Order").Value = lblIDHoldOrder.Text
        rs.Update()
        rs.Close()
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("Error while opening Recordset.")
End If
```

Comment: Ooh..it worked thanks...just a question, why we put recordcount > 0?

Comment: @Sam1996 - If the `recordset` contains records (in fact, 1), then this means that the group already exists in the database. If it does not exist, then there would be 0 record.